# How to Create a dynamic xpath which have only styles no class or id

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

How can I create a dynamic XPath for this elemant, Here is no class or id but just inline CSS. And I need to increment the div number too like this

```html
<div role="none" style="position: relative; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; overflow: hidden; align-items: center; border-radius: 0px; cursor: pointer; padding: 4px 10px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); min-height: 55px;"><div role="none" style="position: relative; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; overflow: hidden; align-items: center; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><div role="none" aria-hidden="true" style="position: relative; display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; overflow: visible; align-items: stretch; width: 40px; height: 40px; justify-content: center;"><div role="none" style="position: absolute; display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; overflow: hidden; align-items: center; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; justify-content: center;"><div role="none" style="position: relative; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; overflow: hidden; align-items: center; background-color: rgb(229, 228, 232); width: 40px; height: 40px; border-radius: 20px; justify-content: center;"
```

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div

/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div
```

Answer (score 0):

In the DOM , you can find the any of the parent which has  id/ class name. '
then you can go with parent- child relation ship.

Format : //tagname[@locator='locatorvalue']

Use the above format for the parent which has the id or class name then navigate to the respective child

//tagname[@locator='locatorvalue']/childtagename1/childtagename2

or

//tagname[@locator='locatorvalue']//childtagename5

Comment: It keeps changing the id bro!

Comment: for the webelement  it is changing, what about the parent id/classnames. Please do share the screenshot of the DOM and the webelement you want to select

Answer (score 0):

Try to create formatted string and just put in it what you want

```
string searchvalue = "position: relative; or whatever"
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format(".//div[contains(@style,'{0}')]", searchvalue)));
```